# display deep hierarchical data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hierarchy

What is the best way to display a lot of hierarchical data in ASP.NET? The browser takes a lot of time to re-render the content and postback will be big. Are there any lightweight components available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 You can try `TreeView Jquery` component

LInk : http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/treeview

2 You can try with `TreeView control`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx

Sample

[image]

Nota : In order to optimize your responses, you acn associate `UpdatePanel` to your control

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider only displaying the first two or three levels upon initial page load. When the user wants to expand a node, you can use AJAX to retrieve only the extra data for that node's children.

If you do not need the features of postback, ie: if this is display only, then you can turn off viewstate.